# Trouble inserting to a set

Tags: c++, set, relational-database

I am trying to add a `Tuple` which inherits from `vector<string>` to a set. (I have read this is bad practice but my professor told us this and said for this assignment he wants us to inherit from `vector<string>` anyways) I have a map which holds a string as the key and a `Relation` as the value. `Relation` is a class which we are building for this assignment. In `Relation` there is a `set<Tuple>` where a `Tuple` is essentially a `vector<string>`. My problem is that when I try to add a `Tuple` to an instance of `Relation` I am unable to do so.

The first time I attempt to add to the set, the size of the set changes from 0 to 1 (successful insert) but each attempt after the first one the size remains at 1 (failed attempt).

I have included the area of code where I have narrowed the problem down too and have included everything that I believe needs to be but it has been a long day so forgive if I have missed something.

```
//Interpreter file


Database dataBase;

void Interpreter::createDatabase(){

  for(unsigned int z = 0; z < dp.getFacts().size(); z++){
    string relName = dp.getFacts()[z].getName();
    vector<string> tup;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < dp.getFacts()[z].getParams().size(); i++){
      tup.push_back(dp.getFacts()[z].getParams()[i].getName());
    }
    dataBase.addTuple(relName,tup);
  }

}
```

```
//in the Database.cpp file

map<string,Relation> db;

void Database::addTuple(string name, vector<string> tuple){ 
  Relation temp = db.at(name);

  temp.addTuple(tuple); 

  db.at(name) = temp;

}
```

```
// in the Relation.cpp File

set<Tuple> tuples;

void Relation::addTuple(vector<string> tuple){
  Tuple t = Tuple(tuple);

  tuples.insert(t);
}
```

```
// Tuple Class

vector<string> values;

Tuple::Tuple(){}

Tuple::Tuple(vector<string> val){
  values = val;
}

Tuple::~Tuple(){}

string Tuple::toString(){
  string str = "";
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++){
    str = str + values[i] + ".";
  }
  return str;
}
```

Comment: use the debugger and watch for the `addTuple(...)` methods. A `set<...>` usually only accepts unique items. Probably your `vector<string>` tuples are not unique. You my provide a proper comparison operator method via overloading.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but you were correct! Thank you for the help! @woodz

Comment: you are welcome. I would appreciate, if you vote up and accept my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of the debugger and watch for the

```
addTuple(...)
```

methods.

A `set<...>` usually only accepts unique items. Probably your `vector<string>` tuples are not unique.

You may provide a proper comparison operator method via overloading as well.